# Html Anchor text formatting

Tags: html, anchor

This may be a basic question but I am using HTML anchor, with the text of the anchor as a multi line paragraph. I have `<br>` tags in the textpart of anchor which are currently not recognized (all text is in one line in output).
Code for anchor tag is as follows:

```
    <li>
     <a href="" title="View all ">Printed Documents
       <br>Total distinct count: 88
       <br>Top docs are:
       <br>RevA02A rework for N3784.doc
       <br>PO33006230.pdf
     </a>
   </li>
```

How do I have anchor text to be formatted on multiple lines?
**Updated:**
This list is passed to a js-mindmap.js which generates nodes with the content as this anchor text. I think its somewhere that `<br/>` tags is escaped..I tried setting the style also but still on 1 line.

Comment: Something else might be messing with your styling. `br` tags in an anchor tag are perfectly fine. See: http://jsfiddle.net/gm7nL/

Comment: Stop doing whatever it is you are doing to stop the line breaks being displayed the way you want.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Install/enable the dev tools for your browser.  Drill down and examine the `<br/>` elements and see if there is a style in your css that is changing their behavior.

Comment: I did a firebug check on the element and see that <br> tags are totally being removed..!

Comment: The <br> tags are interpreted by the javascript, I did an alert of the value inside the js and its printing in a formatted way, now since its formatting it parses and removes the <br> tag, so I want the js not to parse it as a <br> tag but as part of the anchor text. SOhow do I escape the parsing of the <br> tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a{display:block;}`, and your br tags should be XHTML so `<br />`