# How to make a newline inside the html tag <a> with CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists, newline

I would like to know how to make a newline inside the html tag  with CSS. The explanation is as below:

This is the code HTML that I have:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="mess_menu" role="menu"><li style="border-bottom: 1px #D3D3D3;border-bottom-style: solid;"><span style="display:block; width: 200px">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property.The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property.</span></li></ul>
```

This is the code CSS (it belongs to the menu):

```
#mess_menu{
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 360px;
  width: 400px;              
}
```

And this is the screenshot what I obtain on the screen:

[image]

If I change the code HTML above by adding the tag `<a>` as below (notice that I put `<a href="" style="display:block;">`) :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="mess_menu" role="menu"><li style="border-bottom: 1px #D3D3D3;border-bottom-style: solid;"><a href="" style="display:block;"><span style="display:block; width: 200px">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property.The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property.</span></a></li></ul>
```

The menu will appear on my screen as below:

[image]

As you can notice from the screenshot above, the content of the `<li>` has changed and the totality of the text is not shown (only "The numbers in the table specify the first br" is shown").

So, my questions are:

1. How to make a newline inside the html tag `<a>` in order to make all the content of the tag  (which is contained inside the tag `<a>`) appear?
2. If it is possible, how to make it with CSS?

Comment: Give the `a` a `display: inline-block`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html Anchor text formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120816/html-anchor-text-formatting)

Comment: I did put `display: inline-block` for the tag `<a>` but it didn't work!

Comment: It's not just that. Check the duplicate.

Comment: Well I don't have any `<br>` tags inside the `<a>`, I have just `<span>` and this is its code: `<span style="display:block; width: 200px">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property.The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property.</span>`

Comment: What purpose does your `span` serve, that can't already be done on the `li` tag? And why not just increase the overall width of the text and have it naturally line break, similar to what was happening in your first screenie?

Comment: @slime: I am trying to build a menu for a notification system like what we see on Facebook. For example, as you know, when you are notified by a comment of a someone on Facebook, you will see  the `li` (the item) of the belonged menu containing a message of more than one line (like for example: "Jean Paul likes your comment:'bla bla bla'"). Therefore, I put inside the tag `<li>` a `<a>` and I put inside `<a>` a `<span>` which itself contains the message of the notification. So, as you see, I need to make a newline inside the tag `<a>` because I make the width of the menu unchangeable.

Comment: Your second code as posted already wraps:  http://jsfiddle.net/oesu0sy2/  Can you post a Fiddle or Snippet of your problem, so we can see what other styles may be causing the problem?

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Well, actually, I'am using the bootstrap menu. As you can notice, I put `class="dropdown-menu pull-right"` for the tag `<ul>`. Therefore, I guess that the problem comes from the CSS class `dropdown-menu pull-right`.

Comment: That could very well be the problem.  I'm not familiar with Bootstrap, but if you add the bootstrap tag to your post and add a Fiddle or Snippet, someone can probably help you.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: I think I found the code of the class. This is it:
`.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}`. What is strange is that there is the attribute `display` is set to `block` (look at this line `display: block;`). Anyway, Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<br>` tag and it is working.

Comment: I can't insert `<br>` inside `<span>` as it depends on the content of `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, Bootstrap adds `white-space: nowrap` to `a` tags within a `dropdown-menu`.

You can override that by adding this style:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

### Fiddle